# Retrive List of Slack Team from App or user

Tags: slack, slack-api

1) Is there any way to retrive list of team which is associated with slack user?

2) Is there any way to retrive all distributed team of slack app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no, I don't think so
2. yes, you will usually store the team related access token you receive during installation. You can then use [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) to get the team Id and team name for each access token.